# Double ng-repeat splice to remove item?

Tags: angularjs

It all works, but it removes all the 'places' where the 'foobar' is in.

```
$scope.remove = function(foobar) {

    $http.post('/foobar', foobar)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {   
            $scope.account.places.splice($scope.account.places.indexOf(foobar), 1); // works

            // I thought this below will work, but that doesn't work:
            // $scope.account.places.users.splice($scope.account.places.users.indexOf(foobar), 1);
        });
}

<section ng-repeat="place in account.places">
    <section ng-repeat="foobar in place.users">
        {{ foobar.name }}
        <a ng-click="remove(foobar)">&times;</a>
    </section>
</section>
```

How to remove just the specific "foobar" item?

Answer (score 2):

`$scope.account.places` appears to be an array. In your non-functioning version, you are not applying an index to that array to get the appropriate `place.users` array.

One possible way to fix this is to pass `place` to your `remove` method. Then your markup would look like this:

```
<a ng-click="remove(place, foobar)">&times;</a>
```

And your script would look like this:

```
$scope.remove = function(place, foobar) {
    $http.post('/foobar', foobar)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {   
        place.users.splice(place.users.indexOf(foobar), 1);
    });
}
```

This is assuming that Array.indexOf will work for your purpose.

Comment: Thats correct, its an array. How can i fix  my js so it works?

Comment: Added one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this a while ago. I use this line of code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="array.inside_array.splice($index, 1)[0]">{{items + $index}}</a>
```

$index is the index reference in the ng-repeat.

[Check it out!](http://plnkr.co/edit/oTZu1CHgZz82A869LiWL)